# Does Javascript support reflection and can I get a list of classes an object extends?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to get a list of classes an object extends in Javascript? Does Javascript support reflection like this?

I found the Reflect class but I can't get it any class name information out of it.

```
var element = document.createElement("textarea");
console.log(element.nodeName); // TEXTAREA
var proto = Reflect.getPrototypeOf(element);
log(proto.name); // error
```

```js
var element = document.createElement("textarea");
console.log("Name: " + element.nodeName);
var object = Reflect.getPrototypeOf(element);
console.log(object.nodeName); // error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your current code is that `.nodeName` refers to `Node.prototype.nodeName`, which is a getter - but the getter only works when the `this` (the instance it's called on) is an actual element. It doesn't work when `this` is something else, like a prototype object.

To get all prototypes, you can keep calling `Object.getPrototypeOf` and reassigning the prototype, until you reach the end of the prototype chain.

To get the name from each prototype object, assuming they're constructor prototypes, you can access their `.constructor.name` properties.

```js
let obj = document.createElement("textarea");
const prototypes = [];
while (obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)) {
  prototypes.push(obj);
}
for (const proto of prototypes) {
  console.log(proto.constructor.name);
}
```

Comment: When I run your example it works great! But when I run it line by line in the console the node name is an empty string. It might be a different issue but I've encountered something like this before. Are the objects a proxy and does that matter when accessing properties in the console?

Comment: Not sure what you're doing, but accessing `obj.nodeName` should throw `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation` because the getter can't be invoked on a non-element. Accessing `prototypes.nodeName` will just give `undefined` because it's an array.